# Incorrect in gradle setting?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hey guys when i am build app in android studio the some unknown files (.hprof)are created and compiler give error which show in image[image]

my gradle setting

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

-RangeBar

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


 }

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
//   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
 // compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0-rc3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"

   // multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
   //        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
   //        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
  //        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

-app

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
 //buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
 // compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.0-rc3'
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.autoflik.cadlr"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 27
    versionName "1.5"
    multiDexEnabled true
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
    multiDexEnabled = true


}
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"


}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
    abortOnError false
    // if true, only report errors
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
 }




dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':multi-image-selector')
compile project(':RangeBar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
////////tanuj
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'



 //
 //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 //    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
 //    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
 //    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.1'
 //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
//    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
//    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
//    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Please provide solution i have working since last two days but result not found .
i hv changes in gradle setting and now not able to undo it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `android {}`

```
 dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ